# Removing object array entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0:  {id: "201158", salary: 2}
1:  {id: "1627761", salary: 5}
length:2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Above is my object from console. I'm drawing a blank on something here. On click, I'm trying to remove an element by the value of the id.

So for example, if the div clicked has an id of ***201158*** the id and salary would be removed from this array. I've tried delete with no luck. I've tried iterating through the array and hitting it with the below, but nothing.

```
var id = $(this).attr('id').toString(); 

removeFunction(teamOneSalaries, "id", id);

function removeFunction (myObjects,prop,valu)
{
   return myObjects.filter(function (val) {
      return val[prop] !== valu;
   });    
}
```

Any ideas as to what I could be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the function returns a new filtered array you need to assign it back to the variable. i.e.:

```
teamOneSalaries = removeFunction(teamOneSalaries,"id",id);
```

For whatever reason if you don't want to do that and want to update the array passed into the function you will have to remove items directly from that array instead of returning a new one.

e.g.

```
function removeFunction(myObjects, prop, valu) {   
  for (let i = myObjects.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (myObjects[i][prop] === valu)
      myObjects.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myArray = [{id: "201158", salary: 2},{id: "1627761", salary: 5}];
    
myArray = myArray.filter(function( obj ) {
    return obj.id !== '1627761';
});

console.log(myArray);
```

it's working fine with this code

```
var myArray = [{id: "201158", salary: 2},{id: "1627761", salary: 5}];

myArray = myArray.filter(function( obj ) {
   return obj.id !== '1627761';
});

console.log(myArray);
```